# How get value in parent element? (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, element, parent

How can i get value in `<tr cost="xx.xx">` if i click on some button with `id="minus"` or `id="plus"`?

http://jsfiddle.net/YD9uB/3/

Comment: You shouldn't have duplicate `ID`'s. Change 'em to classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method.

```
var cost = $("#minus").closest("tr").attr("cost");
```

However, you really shouldn't use non standard html attributes. You could use data attributes instead:

```
<table>
  <tr data-cost="xx.xx">
    <td>
    <input type="submit" id="minus"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And then access them with the [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

```
var data = $("#minus").closest("tr").data();
var cost = data.cost;
```

**Update**

Here it is inside a click handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".plus, .minus").click(function() {
        var data = $(this).closest("tr").data();
        var cost = data.cost;
        alert(cost);
    });
});
```

With the following updated html that doesn't have duplicate ids:

```
<form>
    <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>quantity</th>
            <th>cost</th>
        </tr>
        <tr data-cost="50.00">
            <td></td>
            <td>Some Name A</td>
            <td>
                <img class="minus button" align="LEFT" src="./img/minus.png" alt="-">
                <input type="text" value="20" name="quantity">
                <img class="plus button" align="RIGHT" src="./img/plus.png" alt="+">
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-cost="80.00">
            <td></td>
            <td>Some Name B</td>
            <td>
                <img class="minus button" align="LEFT" src="./img/minus.png" alt="-">
                <input type="text" value="10" name="quantity">
                <img class="plus button" align="RIGHT" src="./img/plus.png" alt="+">
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</form>​
​
```

[Here's the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrummell/YD9uB/4/)

Comment: and also $("#minus").closest("tr").data("cost");

Comment: i cant know before which buttom will be click ('#plus' or '#minus')

Comment: Are you trying to do this in the click handler?

Comment: i am sorry, i want say class, not ID

Comment: i change html, but dont work.

i look again in morning. thank you